# Regex match characters between two characters NON inclusive in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, react-router

I have a url that I want to route to with React router. The id at the end is the part that changes.

```
https://mywebsite.com/p/foo-bar-fizz-buzz-myid1234
```

What is the correct regular expression that I need to use in react router? Right now I have the following.

```
<Route path="(p\/(.*-))":myId component={myComponent} />
```

Its my understanding that I need to grab the values after the 'p/' up to and including the last dash. I've seen answers involving look arounds but those arent supported in Javascript. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood, you do want to match everything until the last dash.

That can be accomplished with this expression.

```
/\/p\/.+\-/
```

- match /p/
- match one or more of any character but line breaks. This will continue as long as it matches.
- force it to match `-`, so it will stop the previous expression here.

React Router uses [`path-to-regexp`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) so your code should work with this solution

```
<Route path="(p\/(.+\-)):myId" component={myComponent} />
```

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. I think including the 'p/' is messing it up

Comment: please write exactly what you tried. if you try the first regex I wrote, you will see, that it matches perfectly. so maybe it is just the `path-to-regex` implementation that does not work properly.